# Identify the smallest sigma-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains the set [0, 1]

Tags: measure-theory

This is a past exam question which I've tried to do this myself, though I'm unsure of the solution.

First of all, by the definition of a sigma algebra, I should include $\emptyset$. 
Then, complements. Let $A=[0, 1]$.
$A^\complement = (-\infty, 0)\cup(1, \infty)$
$\emptyset^\complement$ = $\mathbb{R}$

And I think that's it under countable unions and intersections... So is this the answer to the question?

{$[0,1], (-\infty, 0)\cup(1, \infty), \emptyset, (-\infty, \infty)$}

I'm not even sure if that's how I should format the answer, I've never seen an example like this before.

Comment: I believe you're correct; your approach was that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $[0,1]$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $[0, 1]$, and that is the correct approach to seeing what $\sigma$-algebra a set generates.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "generated by"? Is this just the term used to describe the approach of taking [0.1] and considering what you'd need to add to it to have a $\sigma$-algebra? Thanks.

Comment: It's more usual to define the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family of sets to be the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing that family.  But that's actually equivalent to taking the family and "considering what you'd need to add to that family" to get a $\sigma$-algebra.  Since you have only one set, the second 'definition' is easier to apply.

Comment: I'm hopeful that any example where I'll have to do this will be of only one set; it's a fairly introductory course. But I'll bear that in mind should a family of more than one set come up, thanks for your help.

Comment: @grantfgates: it's equally common to define the generated $\sigma$-algebra using closure operations. Much like how you would define the free group generated by $S$, or the vector space spanned by $B$, or the polynomial ring with $X$ as the set of indeterminate variables.

Answer (score 0):

If any $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb{R}$ contains $[0,1]$ then it contains all those sets you described, as you have shown.

Those sets you have described also form a $\sigma$-algebra.

Do you see how these together imply that this is the smallest sigma algebra containing the set $[0,1]$?

This is a specific example of the general task of finding $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ the sigma algebra *generated* by a class of sets $\mathcal{F}$.